# No converter found capable of converting from type AbstractJpaQueryTupleConverterTupleBackedMap to Custom Java POJO Class

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am trying to read a list of values from a native Query in JPA .

My Repository Interface is

```
@Query(value = "SELECT E_MAIL AS email FROM USERS WHERE UID = ?1 ",nativeQuery = true )
public List<AuditPipeLineModel> getAuditPipeLine(@Param("uid") String uid);
```

My Model Class is

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class AuditPipeLineModel {
private String email;
}
```

Am getting an exception as

```
No converter found capable of converting from type 
[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to 
type [AuditPipeLineModel]
```

What is the mistake i am doing ?

The Native Query and Model class is much bigger than this , i just avoided it to make it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new package.towards.AuditPipeLineModel(E_MAIL) FROM USERS WHERE UID = ?1 ",nativeQuery = true )
public List<AuditPipeLineModel> getAuditPipeLine(@Param("uid") String uid);
```